# RS232 comm problem

Tags: rs232

I have two devices (Lambda power supply and custom controller) that communicate via RS232 at 9600 baud using 3 wires. A direct connection does not work properly (PS doesn't respond) but if I connect thru a PC using a pass-thru program (Termite from Compuphase), it works fine. I've checked amplitude, offset and timing of the serial signal with an oscilloscope and it looks fine. Direct fails but buffering thru a PC works. Ridiculous. Lambda end is using a MAX202EESE (pins 13 & 14) and the controller a MAX232A (pins 13 & 14). Anyone ever heard of any issues communicating between these two chips?

Comment: Did you swap TX and RX signals? Because...it only makes sense that the transmit wire leaving one device ends up at the receive wire of the other device. Because if they both have the same connector and if each connector expects to be plugged into a PC, then if you just directly plug both connectors to each other then you get both transmit lines connecting together and both receive lines connecting together.

Comment: When you are doing the direct connect have you made sure that you have actual Tx -> Rx and the other Rx -> Tx?  Sometimes the port names do not represent the actual signal flow direction.

Comment: Yep. TX and RX are correct...

Comment: @ksquared - Hi, I don't know if you're still looking for help. If I was in your situation, I would provide scope traces from the PSU end of the connection (a) when the PSU is connected directly to the custom controller (not working), and (b) with the PSU connected to the PC acting as a form of RS-232 repeater (if I understand things correctly - a diagram of the working vs. non-working setups would help to confirm things). There must be a difference between the two scope traces (a) and (b), otherwise both configs would behave the same. Next steps would depend on the differences identified. HTH!